# Unable to get the Query String value

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I'm hitting this URL getting vToken is nothing. Please assist

```
Dim vHDR As String = Nothing
If Request.IsLocal Then 
     Dim vToken = Request.QueryString("approvalToken")
     If Not vToken Is Nothing Then
         Dim vUser = Helper.ValidateToken(vToken)
         If Not vUser Is Nothing Then
              vHDR = vUser
          End If
      End If
 End If
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:56979/#/modules/Review?ID=20582&approvalToken=SIsJ3swuGjpPidOvWPSzuqfcTJH8IywIlVVEnkmIQU6yE93PUQ
```

Comment: Posting a link to _localhost_ it is pretty useless

Comment: a localhost link won't work for anyone not using your PC

Comment: Relax, people. localhost to a high port number is normal when working with Visual Studio. It's just a temporary web server for use while still developing the app. When the site is ready to go live, it will push to a new server with a real domain name.

Answer (score 0):

In a URL, everything beginning with the hash sign (`#`) is called the [`Fragment Identifier`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). The fragment identifier section is the *last* section of the URL and comes *after* the url arguments.

So for this url from the question:

```
http://localhost:56979/#/modules/Review?ID=20582&approvalToken=SIsJ3swuGjpPidOvWPSzuqfcTJH8IywIlVVEnkmIQU6yE93PUQ
```

there is no query string. The section that looks like a query string was pre-empted to be part of a very long fragment identifier. Even the `/modules/Review` section that looks like part of the Path is actually part of the fragment.

I suspect somewhere in your base/index page you have a link with a blank href value, which is sometimes expressed with a single hash (`#`). You click that link, which puts the hash sign into the url:

```
http://localhost:56979/#
```

After clicking this link, you then redirect, click a new link, or do some other action that appends the **relative url** `/modules/Review` (which may already include the query string) to your current location. But now you have the hash sign as part of that existing location, and so you end up with the url in your question, which doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

I'd have to see a lot more code to tell you exactly how to fix this, but in the context of vb.net (asp.net), if this code runs on the server you probably want to change `/modules/Review` to `~/modules/Review`. If this is done in javascript, I'd need to know more about your page.